# How to tell start menu search in Windows 10 what to search

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I like the start menu search as a way to quickly launch software. By default it will find applications which added a link to the start menu. I also found out that it will search the desktop as well, when I add the folder in "Indexing Options".

But it seems to ignore other folders. I have a "tools" folder where I store many utility applications. Even after adding this folder in Indexing Options content of the folder don't appear in start menu search.

Any hints how I get the start menu search to list files from arbitrary folders?

Comment: You can't get windows to search none default folders straight from the start menu.

But, it sounds like you want to easily access a folder, have you tried pinning the folder to the toolbar?

Comment: I actually want to quickly type the tool name I want to start. I'm not interested in opening the folder.

Comment: @user4085 Is your 'Tools' folder a collection of shortcuts, or the programs themselves?

Comment: No, I store applications (EXE) there, which need no installation.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you've asked for, but it's a solution that may work for you as there isn't a way (at least, a documented way) to change the Windows start menu search locations.

1. Create a folder in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\`, call it what you like, for example, `Tools`
2. Within this folder, create shortcuts to the utilities (they must be shortcuts, EXE's are ignored) you wish to be able to access. Again, call them what you like (this will be the name you type into the `search` bar

It may take a few seconds to update, but you should be able to search and open them the same way as any other program.